# How to retrieve sentence data in chronological order?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that stores customer chat data with a service agent. It has the following columns:
`customer_id, chat_date, chat_id, sentence_id, timestamp`.

customers can have multiple records, `chat_id` is the parent grouping of a conversation, `sentence_id` makes up each sentence of the conversation (thus a `chat_id` will have multiple `sentence_id`'s). timestamp is the time the sentence in the conversation was sent - so different sentence_id's for the same chat_id will have different time stamps (for precision, lets say it go down to the second)

1. How can I query this to get the correct order of the conversation?
2. Is this a partition by type of statement?
3. Could someone please give me the proper syntax?

Update:

I would want the following tabular type of results:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|customer_id|chat_id|sentence_id|timestamp       |
--------------------------------------------------
|123        |ABC    |1          |01-01-2009 6:00:01 
--------------------------------------------------
|123        |ABC    |20         |01-01-2009 6:00:02
--------------------------------------------------
|123        |ABC    |10         |01-01-2009 6:00:03
--------------------------------------------------
|123        |ABC    |5          |01-01-2009 6:00:04
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: is `sentence_id` a sequence? is the timestamp for the sentence, the chat or the record?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @blurfus I updated it. the timestamp is for the sentence_id, each sentence_id rolls up to a parent chat_id

Answer (score 1):

If `timestamp` was recorded right, probably you can do:

```
create table conversations as
select * from chat_raw_data
order by customer_id, chat_id, timestamp;
```

Comment: timestamp is ordered but sentence_id is nonsequential

Comment: So, try the first code I provided

Comment: One more question...what if sentence_id is sequential, but it's with text. For example, something like: message-1-1, message-1-2, message 2-1, etc...

Comment: Updated my answer after you updated your question

Comment: Probably ordering by timestamp will order by sentence_id as well. You can also order strings in alphabetical order. You can add sentence_id to the end of the order list just to be sure

Comment: Check if this works. If don't, you may need to substring the number sequence from sentence_id.

Comment: @LuizZ why you are using create table statement in your answer?

Comment: I used create table to save the results in a new table. Wasn't it appropriate?